# When setting DB column to allow NULL in Database the app complains about the Schema

Tags: android-room

I am trying to use Room in Android Studio using Kotlin with a pre-packaged database. The database does not set NOT NULL. Using DB SQL Browser it shows that the column has these properties

"Reference" TEXT

There is no NOT NULL. All the other columns in the table do have NOT NULL set.

In the Entity that maps that table I have:

```
@Entity
data class Meaning (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "Id") val id: Int,
    @NonNull @ColumnInfo(name = "Contents") val contents: String,
    /*
     * It's OK for Reference to be Null
     */
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Reference") val reference: String,
    @NonNull @ColumnInfo(name = "SymbolId") val symbolId: Int,
    @NonNull @ColumnInfo(name = "Local") val local: Int
    )
```

It builds and installs, but fails when running with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: Meaning(<stuff>.Meaning).
     Expected:
TableInfo{name='Meaning', <unimportant columns>,  Reference=Column{name='Reference', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'},<more unimportant columns>}
     Found:
TableInfo{name='Meaning', <unimportant columns>, Reference=Column{name='Reference', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, <more unimportant columns}
```

Note that the Found has notNull=false, which seems correct because NOT NULL is not specified in the database.
The Expected has notNull=true even though in the Entity, @NonNull was not specified for the Reference column.

So, I am confused why the Entity is expecting Reference column to be notNull=true.

Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "Reference") val reference: String?,
```

would equate to notNull = false.

i.e. the **?** indicates null allowed.

> So, I am confused why the Entity is expecting Reference column to be notNull=true.

Because the annotation processing sees **String** which cannot be null. Only if it sees **String?** then can the value be nullable.

That is if you you use:-

```
@Entity
data class Meaning (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "Id") val id: Int,
    @NonNull @ColumnInfo(name = "Contents") val contents: String,
    /*
     * It's OK for Reference to be Null
     */
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Reference") val reference: String?,
    @NonNull @ColumnInfo(name = "SymbolId") val symbolId: Int,
    @NonNull @ColumnInfo(name = "Local") val local: Int
)
```

and then compile, the generated Java (**expected**) for the @Database annotated class suffixed with _Impl includes:-

```
_db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Meaning` (`Id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `Contents` TEXT NOT NULL, `Reference` TEXT, `SymbolId` INTEGER NOT NULL, `Local` INTEGER NOT NULL)");
```

i.e.

```
, `Reference` TEXT,
```

However without the **?** then :-

```
_db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Meaning` (`Id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `Contents` TEXT NOT NULL, `Reference` TEXT NOT NULL, `SymbolId` INTEGER NOT NULL, `Local` INTEGER NOT NULL)");
```

i.e.

```
`Reference` TEXT NOT NULL,
```

Comment: I tried that first thing, but when I add that '?' the build fails with "Each bind variable in the query must have a matching method parameter. Cannot find method parameters for :cat. - database.symbol.SymbolDao.getSymbolsByCategoryId(int)"
Which is a DAO for a completely different Entity. So, I just figured that confused  the building of the Entity. Take the '?' out and the build succeeds, but have the original problem.

Comment: I tried changing the Contents field to not have @NonNull in the Entity and added the '?' to the String and it built and of course the App errored on it and the error message showed that Content was notNull=false. So, I guess I just need to figure out why the build fails when I put the '?' on Reference. Probably some weird syntax thing that I am just not seeing right now. Thanks!!

Comment: @chriskot, first try clean project and rebuild, see if that clears the issue.

Comment: I removed comments in the SmbolDAO that was creating the build error and can now get the app started when using the '?'. Thanks